# Frameworks para uso de Máscaras em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

No caso de campos com máscaras (CNPJ, por exemplo) e/ou data, qual *framework* UI *free* seria mais recomendado?

- Javascript ou;
- jQuery ou;
- Kendo ou;
- AngularJs ou;
- Sei lá qual mais.

Não sei se consegui ser bem claro, mais resumindo: qual o *framework* UI *free* mais recomendado para campos com máscaras, data (que abre o calendário), monetário, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No caso de campos com mascaras (CNPJ por ex) e/ou data, qual framework ui free seria mais recomendado?

Você pode usar o [jQuery.MaskedInput](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.MaskedInput/), que pode ser usado em conjunto com qualquer um dos frameworks citados.

Uso:

```
$("#Cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
```

> qual o framework ui free mais recomendado para campos com mascaras, data (que abre o calendário), monetário,...

A pergunta é baseada em opiniões, mas vou tentar ir por um lado mais objetivo.

Para máscaras, o jQuery Masked Input resolve a maioria dos casos.

Para datas que abrem um calendário há várias opções. Uma boa opção é o [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) do [jQuery UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined/).

Para dinheiro, uma excelente opção é o [jQuery Money Mask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JQuery.MoneyMask/).

Exemplo de uso:

```
$("#Valor").maskMoney({
    prefix:'R$ ', 
    allowNegative: true, 
    thousands:'.', 
    decimal:',', 
    affixesStay: false
});
```